# Angular component property values gone after changing route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new to Angular development. I was trying to build a recipe list component where you add recipe items in a list by calling an api and pushing the returned recipe object into the list. it works fine. But as soon as I change the route to some other route everything resets.
Heres the code for `recipe-list.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RecipeModel } from '../recipe.model';
import { axiosClient } from '../../axiosApi/axiosApi';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-list',
  templateUrl: './recipe-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-list.component.css']
})

export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
  private axiosClient: axiosClient;
  recipeList: RecipeModel[] = [];
  constructor(axiosClient: axiosClient) { 
    this.axiosClient = axiosClient;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getRandomRecipe(): void {
    this.getRandomRecipeHelper()
    .then(recipe => {
      this.recipeList.push(recipe);
    });
  }

  async getRandomRecipeHelper(): Promise<RecipeModel> {
    try {
      let recipeObject = await this.axiosClient.get<any>({
        url: "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php",
      });
      let meal_info: any = recipeObject.meals[0];
      let title = meal_info['strMeal'];
      let body = meal_info['strInstructions'];
      let category = meal_info['strCategory'];
      let area = meal_info['strArea'];
      let thumbnail = meal_info['strMealThumb'];
      let link = meal_info['strYoutube'];
      let ingredients: {name: string, measure: string}[] = [];
      for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        if (meal_info['strIngredient' + i] !== "" && meal_info['strMeasure' + i] !== "") {
          ingredients.push({'name': meal_info['strIngredient' + i], 'measure': meal_info['strMeasure' + i]});
        }        
      }
      let recipe = new RecipeModel(title, body, category, area, thumbnail, link, ingredients);
      return new Promise<RecipeModel>((resolve, reject) => {resolve(recipe)});
    }
    catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  
}
```

I have the recipe-list component inside a `recipe.component.ts` which is at `/recipes`, there are also `/shopping` and `/home`.
If someone can help me out on what exactly is the problem here that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: This does not happen when I manually populate the list array from inside the recipe-list class definition. So the problem seems to be with the axiosClient observable.

Comment: the problem is not clear! what has been reseted? maybe you can add your route config

Comment: I think I figured it out. Apparently Angular destroys the component for a route when we change thr route. So everytime I switch to some other route and go back to /recipes, the RecipeComponent gets reconstructed and so the RecipeListComponent inside it also gets reset and so the array initialises to an empty array.

Comment: However, the state does not persist on page reload. That however is a different problem and I need to use ngRx for that maybe. I was wondering if there was any other way to ensure data persistence after page reload without relying on server-side?

Comment: maybe learn about RouteReuseStrategy